# Generating excel sheet from PHP code

Tags: php

I want to generate an excel sheet from PHP code. I googled and found some solution,one of them is directly generating from http headers

```
<?php
    header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
    header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=spreadsheet.xlsx" );

    // print your data here. note the following:
    // - cells/columns are separated by tabs ("\t")
    // - rows are separated by newlines ("\n")

    // for example:
    echo 'First Name' . "\t" . 'Last Name' . "\t" . 'Phone' . "\n";
    echo 'John' . "\t" . 'Doe' . "\t" . '555-5555' . "\n";
?>
```

Other way is by using PHPExcel class. Another way is by using Jquery

Is generating excel using HTTP headers a correct way of doing or is there any other simple method of doing this. Which method do u suggest me to use

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [writing a CSV](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php):

```
<?php
header( "Content-Type:text/csv" );
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, array('this','is some', 'csv "stuff", you know.'));
fclose($out);
?>
```

This file can be readily opened in [Microsoft Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/%E2%80%8E) or any other CSV viewer -- personally, I prefer [R](http://www.r-project.org).